# Problema con string y funciones en C++

Tags: c++, string, function

Hice el programa siguiente con el objetivo de registrar el nombre de una planta, con ayuda de la función `registro();` . Me gustaría que el nombre que registré en esta función también se muestre en la función `familia();`, en particular donde dice `cout << "\n \t Elige la familia de " << nombre << "\n" << endl;` pero hasta ahora no lo he conseguido. Incluso usé apuntadores, pero el compilador arrojó puros errores.

¿Sabrán cómo solucionar este problema?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>     // Español
#include <string>       // Cadenas
#include <fstream>      // Ficheros

using namespace std;

void opuntia();
void registro();
void familia();

int main(){ 
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Spanish"); // Español
    
    int menu, submenu1;
    
    opuntia();
    
    cin >> menu;
    
    if(menu == 1){      
        registro();
        
        familia();
        
        cin >> submenu1;        
    }   
}

// MENÚ PRINCIPAL | OPUNTIA
void opuntia(){
    cout << "\t 1. Registro (taxonomía y cuidados)" << endl;
    cout << "\t 2. Salir \n \n" << endl;
}

// SUBMENÚ 1 | REGISTRO DE NOMBRE
void registro(){    
    string nombre;
    
    cout << "\n \t Ingresa el nombre de la planta" << endl;
    cout << "\t (Máximo 15 caracteres) \n \n" << endl;
    
    cin.clear();
    fflush(stdin);
    
    while (getline(cin, nombre)){
        if (nombre.size() <= 15){
            cout << "\n \t ¿Quieres continuar con el registro de " << nombre << "?\n" << endl;
            system("pause");
            break;  
        }else{
            cout << "\n \t ¡El nombre debe tener un máximo de 15 caracteres! \n" << endl;   
        }
    }   
}

// SUBMENÚ 1 | REGISTRO DE FAMILIA
void familia(){
    string nombre;
    
    cout << "\n \t Elige la familia de " << nombre << "\n" << endl;
    cout << "\t 1. Agavácea" << endl;
    cout << "\t 2. Cactácea" << endl;
    cout << "\t 3. Crasulácea \n" << endl;
    cout << "\t 4. Regresar \n" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Podrías agregar los errores que salen en la consola.

Comment: No deberias pasar nombre como un parametro a la funcion familia?

Comment: Ya que estás usando `cout` con el operador `<<` podrías usar `cin` con `>>` siempre para obtener datos desde la consola y no tener que usar `cin.clear()` o `fflush(stdin)`. Además, mezclarlos puede dar algunos dolores de cabeza.